# DefaultInlineConstraintResolver was unable to resolve CustomRouteConstraint - Web API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

This issue was raise twice on SO, I have tried those solutions, but it is not working for me.

I am trying to create CustomRouteConstraint for a ComplexObject which is a parameter in ActionMethod, where HttpPost is used.

I am following this url to implement Custom Routing.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

**1. Creating CustomRouteConstraint.**

```
 public class CustomRouteConstraint : IHttpRouteConstraint
    {

        public bool Match(HttpRequestMessage request, IHttpRoute route, string parameterName, IDictionary<string, object> values, HttpRouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
            object value;

            if (values.TryGetValue(parameterName, out value) && value != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**2. MapAttribute in WebAPIConfig.cs file**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {

    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        var constraintResolver = new DefaultInlineConstraintResolver();
        constraintResolver.ConstraintMap.Add("CustomObjRouteConstraint", typeof(CustomRouteConstraint));
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(constraintResolver);
       
        
    }
}
```

**3. Using Constraint in ActionMethod.**

```
    [Route("Address/{param:CustomObjRouteConstraint}")]
        [HttpPost]
        public AddressUpdateResult UpdateCustomerAddresses(UpdateCustomerAddressCommand param)
        {
           Handle(param);
            return xyz;
        }
```

At run-time I get error :

> "DefaultInlineResolver was unable to resolve CustomRouteConstraint "